# How to write SQL Pivot

Tags: sql, t-sql

I'm having an issue trying to pivot column data to row data. Here is the table structure:

submission_id itemID, answerValue

There are 21 rows per submission with the same submissionID, the ItemID(question) and answervalue change in each row.
So a row would look like this (abcd1234,7857,'YES')
(abcd1234, 2226,'34 some Street)

I'm trying to create one row with the submission id with all of the itemid and answervalue for that submissionID. Hope this makes sense.

Comment: please provide sample data and desired output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution with `pivot`.

**Sample data**

I added another `submissionId` to the sample data to have an extra result row.

```
create table data
(
  submissionId nvarchar(8),
  itemId int,
  answerValue nvarchar(20)
);

insert into data (submissionId, itemId, answerValue) values
('abcd1234', 7857, 'YES'),
('abcd1234', 2226, '34 some Street'),
('abcd5678', 7857, 'NO'),
('abcd5678', 2226, '100 east lane');
```

**Solution**

```
select piv.submissionId,
       [7857] as Question1,
       [2226] as Question2
from data d
pivot (max(d.answerValue) for d.itemId in ([7857], [2226])) piv;
```

**Result**

```
submissionId Question1 Question2
------------ --------- --------------
abcd1234     YES       34 some Street
abcd5678     NO        100 east lane
```

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=e38d2f061291c278149fd080faad4ffd) to see things in action.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, from the given data i.e. if questions have same ID's, you could use CASE to create pivot:

```
SELECT submission_id, 
       (CASE WHEN itemID=7857 THEN answerValue END) AS Q7857,
       (CASE WHEN itemID=2226 THEN answerValue END) AS Q2226
       ...
FROM table_name
GROUP BY submission_id;
```